# How to select a line in SynEdit when clicked on the left in the gutter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I want to select a line when clicked on its left in the gutter similar to the Delphi code editor (clicking on line number, CNPack installed). I guess the answer lies in selStart, selEnd, smLine selection mode but couldn't make any workable solution.

```
procedure TForm1.SynEdit1GutterClick(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; X,
  Y, Line: Integer; Mark: TSynEditMark);
begin
    SynEdit1.SelectionMode := smLine;
    SynEdit1.SelStart := 0;
    SynEdit1.SelEnd := SynEdit1.Lines[Line].Length;
    SynEdit1.SelectionMode := smNormal; //restore
    //Code not working
    //I don't remember the code which made it select a line with smLine

end;
```

Comment: If you'd made a [mcve] it would make it easy for us to modify it to meet your needs. Without that we have to spend time writing the test bed program.

Comment: I seriously don't understand I have to reproduce event handlers here for people to get started. Every time I get a -1 followed by this very comment. I am doing it anyways.

Comment: We had no indication of which event you were handling. Perhaps there were multiple possibilities and you had chosen the wrong one. If every time you ask a question you get chided for not providing a MCVE don't you think you should listen? Or, if you would rather not, and don't like the way SO works, why not ask somewhere else that is more suited to your expectations?

Comment: For me it is the default behavior in SynEdit. try clicking the the gutter and move the mouse down. the lines are selected.

Comment: That SO link starts this way - "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code....". Excuse me please i have no code to begin with. I was asking if someone knew the synEdit library methods to achieve what i am looking for.

Comment: @kobik the dragging over in the gutter does that but not the click.

Comment: You said similar to the Delphi code editor. when the gutter is clicked in Delphi it does not select the line. have you looked at SynEdit source code BTW?

Comment: @kobik when I click on a line number, it selects the line in my Delphi Editor. I have CNPack installed too.

Comment: Well, you should clearly state all that information in the **question**.

Comment: Clearly you have some code. In fact you posted it here and then removed it, perhaps in pique. Perhaps you'd be better off asking somewhere else that doesn't have the same expectations of askers that SO has. Why not do that?

Comment: I have added it David.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't remember the code which made it select a line with smLine"* in the code comment?  - So, you *did* manage to select a line or not? :)

Comment: I did manage to select the line but the caret was not at the end of the line after selection due to a specific selection length. This was not a good solution.

Comment: Try `SynEdit1.ExecuteCommand(ecSelLineEnd, #0, nil)` on the gutter click event. You need to include the unit `SynEditKeyCmds`.

Comment: @kobik that's the answer. Can you post it as answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ecSelLineEnd` command:

```
SynEdit1.ExecuteCommand(ecSelLineEnd, #0, nil)
```

in the gutter click event.

You need to include the unit `SynEditKeyCmds`